# Tkinter create buttons iteratively, but be able to configure specific buttons

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, button

I need to create 100 buttons in a 10x10 grid. I've done this, and managed to find which button is being pressed using lambda and sending a values along with it (x and y), as shown below.

```
        def button_pressed(buttonx, buttony):
            print(buttonx, buttony)
            if self.currentNonogram[buttony][buttonx] == 1:
                print("correct")
            else:
                print("incorrect")
        # Buttons
        for x in range(1, 11):
            tk.Label(text=self.rows[x-1]).grid(row=x+4, column=2)
            for y in range(1, 11):
                self.labelText = str(self.columns[y-1])
                self.labelText = self.labelText.replace("[", "")
                self.labelText = self.labelText.replace("]", "")
                self.labelText = self.labelText.replace(",", "")
                self.labelText = self.labelText.replace(" ", "\n")
                tk.Label(text=self.labelText).grid(row=3, column=y+2)
                tk.Button(width="1", height="1", command = lambda y=y,x=x:button_pressed(x-1, y-1)).grid(row=x+4, column=y+2)
```

In the function which is called when the buttons are pressed, where it prints "correct" I want to change the background colour of the buttons to black, but I can't figure out a way to configure a specific one of these buttons like this, as usually this would be done by the name, and clearly I don't want to have to create separate names for each button.

Thanks!

Comment: Store the buttons in a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you `bind()` an event to each button, you can use that event to fetch the widget (button, in this case) that triggered it, and then `configure()` the button from there.

```python
# get the buttons in your window 
# (change 'root' to whatever the parent widget of your buttons is)
for btn in root.winfo_children():  
    btn.bind(
        '<Button-1>',  # left click
        lambda event: event.widget.configure(bg='black')
    )
```

This way you can get away with binding events to buttons that don't have names that you've given.

*Edit*

...to say that if you want to *selectively* apply this event binding to a predefined subset of the buttons, you'll just need to modify the `for` loop to look at some iterable of your "correct" buttons rather than all of them, e.g.: `for btn in list_of_correct_buttons:` - the caveat there is that you'll have to figure out how to get those pesky button names (hint: store them ahead of time, like @Bryan Oakley said)

If you want to do more than just change the color, modify the event binding to call a function that does what you want, e.g.:

```python
def check_button(event):  # the event param is passed by the binding below
    # put whatever check you're doing here...
    # you'll still need to know the 'correct' buttons ahead of time
    if event.widget() in list_of_correct_buttons:
        event.widget.configure(bg='black')  # set btn style
        # do whatever else you need to do here


# get the buttons in your window 
# (change 'root' to whatever the parent widget of your buttons is)
for btn in root.winfo_children():  
    btn.bind(
        '<Button-1>',  # left click
        lambda event: check_button(event)  # call custom func
    )
```

Comment: This does change the buttons to black, but how can I use an if statement with this? Because I only want to change them to black if self.currentNonogram[buttony][buttonx] == 1. I also want to be able to change the colour back from black when its pressed again. Any solutions?

Comment: Just create a function that does what you want to do and call it in the event binding instead - see edits above :)